# Login fails when try to connect by app but not by the Management Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a WebSite that just don't connect to database. Both are on my local machine.
Using the same parameters (Host, User ID, Pwd and Database) I can connect with the MS SQL Server Management Studio.

What can by my problem??

Here goes the two ConnectionStrings I'm trying to use:

`Data Source=VIVID-28\MSSQLSERVER1;Initial Catalog=DicionarioDados;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=VIVID-28\Development;Password=*******`

`Server=VIVID-28\MSSQLSERVER1;Database=DicionarioDados;Integrated Security=SSPI;User ID=VIVID-28\Development;Password=*******`

`VIVID-28` Is the name of my machine.
`MSSQLSERVER1` Is the Instance.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?   Authentication failed for user 'VIVID-28\Development'.  Or did you not even get that far.

Comment: Yes @darin, that's the error!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the "Integrated Security=SSPI" section. That means that it uses Windows Authentication and hence will ignore the user name and password you are passing in your connection string.

Answer (score 2):

To test your connection you can try using VS server explorer and by adding connection to your sql server database you can test whether connection can be made with given parameters or not. ones you able to connect you can select the connection and go to properties and copy the connection string and past it as your application connection string.

Answer (score 0):

There can be many reasons of this , see the following similar question and see the links I have given in the post, follow the steps.

[Why I am not able to connect to remote SQL Server from asp.net website whereas it is connecting from SQL Server Management Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9819648/why-i-am-not-able-to-connect-to-remote-sql-server-from-asp-net-website-whereas-i)

Answer (score 0):

Do you work with multiple SQL Servers?

Are you absolutely sure that the SQL Management studio is connecting to the same sql server / instance as your code?  If you have a production and development server, you may have created the user on your production server, but not development, or the password may be incorrect.

Try resetting the password on your development server and see where that takes you. (: